# XUL element to break line

Tags: firefox-addon

I define a label and set its value

```
<bbox>
  <label id="notify" value="Test"/>
</bbox>
```

The width of the label is fix so if the value (text) is longer then the width
I want the line to break. I tried it with css doing

```
word-wrap:break word;
```

But this does not work. Is there a [`XUL element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Reference) that provides such a feature or do you know an other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with either the `<label>` or the `<description>` element, but you need to use its textContent rather than its value.

```
<label id="notify">Test</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a xul [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/description) is what you want.